# Randomizing list processing faster than Collections.shuffle()?

Tags: java, performance, random, collections, shuffle

I am developing an agent-based model in Java. I have used a profiler to reduce any inefficiencies down to the point that the only thing holding it back is Java's **Collections.shuffle()**.

The agents (they're animals) in my model need to be processed in a random order so that no agent is consistently processed before the others.

**I am looking for**: Either a *faster* way to shuffle than Java's Collections.shuffle() or an alternative method of processing the elements in an ArrayList in a randomized order that is *significantly faster*. If you know of a data structure that would be faster than an ArrayList, by all means please answer. I have considered LinkedList and ArrayDeque, but they aren't making much of a difference.

***Currently, I have over 1,000,000 elements in the list I am trying to shuffle. Over time, this amount increases and it is becoming increasingly inefficient to shuffle it.***

**Is there an alternative data structure or way of randomizing the processing of elements that is faster?**

I only need to be able to store elements and process them in a randomized order. I do not use contains or anything more complex than storage and iterating over them.

Here is some sample code to better explain what I am trying to achieve:

**UPDATE:** Sorry for the ConcurrentModificationException, I didn't realize I had done that and I didn't intend to confuse anyone. Fixed it in the code below.

```
ArrayList<Agent> list = new ArrayList<>();
void process()
{
    list.add(new Agent("Zebra"));
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Agent> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.shuffle(list);//Something that will allow the order to be random (random quality does not matter to me), yet faster than a shuffle
        for (String str : list)
        {
            newlist.add(str);
            if(r.nextDouble() > 0.99)//1% chance of adding another agent to the list
            {
                newlist.add(new Agent("Lion"));
            }
        }
        list = newlist;
    }
}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
I thought about doing list.remove(rando.nextInt(list.size()) but since remove for ArrayLists is O(n) it would be even worse to do that rather than shuffle for such a large list size.

Comment: You'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you try that.

Comment: I would not expect any faster approach to shuffling to be physically possible, if you want uniform shuffling.

Comment: The Fisher-Yates shuffle does exactly `n`  exchange operations for an array of size `n`. I very much doubt you can do a uniform shuffle in less than that.

Comment: Though looking at the code, you could get rid of the call to shuffle and get exactly the same result.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to shuffle the entire `List` every iteration, when 90% of the `String`s get ignored anyway. Couldn't you just choose some random indices each time, and only shuffle once at the end of the entire method?

Comment: Some of the comments/answers *seem* to be misled by the code that you posted - I assumed that it was **pseudocode**, only to illustrate the idea. If you provided more information about (or code for) the *real* application case, one could probably give better advice.

Comment: @Marco13 yes it was pseudo-code I am sorry for the mistake (and disappointed that I didn't catch it)

Comment: @PaulBoddington because it is an agent-based model, randomness of element processing is critical to me.

Comment: @biziclop The code I gave is simply sample code. In my agent-based model, animals are placed on an actual lattice and if the first is preferred over the other, the simulation fails to model reality (basically, the population migrates in one direction every time, and the first agent in my Arraylist always survives)

Comment: @LouisWasserman it need only be sufficiently random that a consistent pattern does not manifest itself.

Comment: @Robotia Instead of removing an entry you can just mark it as removed using a flag. That means you need an extra check and re-roll your dice if you hit an entry that is already marked as processed. But if you only select something like 1% of all your elements, these clashes won't happen too often.

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear. First of all: When you are using `new Random()` then it is impossible to measure the execution time. The resulting list size may vary from run to run (and it may vary *dramatically*). Additionally, as it is stated now, one could consider that a simple **random sample** of the input list could be sufficient in order to solve your *actual* problem. But presumably, the condition `r.nextDouble() > 0.99` is once more pseudocode, and the *actual* condition somehow depends on the current `Agent` - e.g. on its "fitness" as probability to create offspring. Right?

Comment: Still, even if the condition depends on something like the "fitness" of the current agent, there certainly are solutions that do **not** involve the expensive `shuffle` of all agents. Most likely something like: "Run over the list, and select the Agents that may produce offspring, randomly, but depending on their fitness".

Comment: @Marco13 one agent cannot be consistently preferred over another. That's why I cannot just iterate over the list. If I were to do that the population would grow in a consistent manner and not represent the real world.

Comment: But as Durandal said: In the current form, it is not clear what the result (outcome) of this function should be. It will add 1% of new Agents, 100000 times. Or to phrase it that way: **The contents of the shufflet list does not seem to be used at all**. Currently, it looks like you could simply randomly generate some new agents.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a simple ArrayList and *not shuffle* it at all. Instead select random list indices to process. To avoid processing a list element twice, I'd remove the processed elements from the list.

Now if the list is very large, removing a random entry itself would be the bottleneck. This can however be avoided easily by removing the *last* entry instead and moving it into the place the selected entry occupied before:

```
public String pullRandomElement(List<String> list, Random random) {
    // select a random list index
    int size = list.size();
    int index = random.nextInt(size);
    String result = list.get(index);
    // move last entry to selected index
    list.set(index, list.remove(size - 1));
    return result;
}
```

Needless to say you should chose a list implementation where get(index) and remove(lastIndex) are fast O(1), such as ArrayList. You may also want to add edge case handling (such as list is empty).

Comment: @Durandal Is ArrayList removal O(1) for removing from the end of a list? I thought it was always O(n) as the Big O Cheat Sheet said... I will test this out tomorrow morning, it looks promising! (It's really late here)

Comment: @Marco13 it ended up being slower than Collections.shuffle()

Comment: @Marco13 I get where you're coming from and took your advice; changed the example to take the Random instance as an argument. While I don't deem it necessary on one hand (example being an example and expect common sense to be applied), the other point - providing well styled examples is equally valid, especially considering what qualifies as common sense differs wildly in SO's audience.

Comment: So after all: A reasonable approach, but probably not "the" solution to the actual problem (which was not really worked out clearly in the question - but maybe the discussion in the comments will help to figure it out...)

Comment: @Marco13 Again I am sorry for the confusion I created.

Comment: @Robotia Maybe you should take a step back and rewrite your question. Your example code is *terrible* at communicating what the actual goal and problem really are. If I take your example code literally, its an utterly convoluted way of copying a list 100k times while adding a few entries. There would be no need to shuffle the list more than once; you could simply just add 100k times 1% times list size random entries and shuffle exactly once - done. Results would be indistinguishable from your example and run in approx. 1/100,000 of the time :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this: If you already have the list of items, generate a random according to its size and get nextInt.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();    
int sizeOfCollection = list.size();

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomId = randomGenerator.nextInt(sizeOfCollection);
Object x = list.get(randomId);
list.remove(randomId);
```

Comment: And what will this accomplish? (Note that the tricky part is not to pick random elements from an unshuffled list, but to process each element exactly *once*, in random order)

Comment: ahhh okay then remove it after... So you pick your element randomly and discard it from your list. You can alway make a copy of your List if you need to keep the original one

Comment: @PatB Marco is right. I need to process each element once in a random order. ArrayList removal is O(n) which ends up being slower than Collections.shuffle() on such a large collection.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code doesn't actually depend on the order of the list, it's enough to shuffle it once at the end of the processing.

```
void process() {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        for (String str : list) {
             if(r.nextDouble() > 0.9) {
                list.add(str + str);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
}
```

Though this would still throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, like the original code.

Comment: My code shown above was just sample code. The actual model I have implemented requires that the elements ALWAYS be processed in a sufficiently random order so that the model is not biased.

Comment: @Robotia There is no bias in this model, as you make a random decision to process each element, which doesn't depend on the position of the element.

Comment: Each element must be processed.

Comment: @Robotia Yes, but whether it is selected or not doesn't depend on its position in the list, only on the result of the random call.

Answer (score 0):

Collections.shuffle() uses the modern variant of Fisher-Yates Algorithm:
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Colections.shuffle convert the list to an array, then does the shuffle, just using random.nextInt() and then copies everything back. (see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

You make this only faster by avoiding the overhead of copying the array and writing back:
Either write your own implementation of `ArrayList` where you can directly access the backing array, or access the field "elementData" of your ArrayList via reflection.

Now use the the same algorithm as Collections.shuffle on that array, using the correct size().
This speeds up, because it avoid the copying if the whole array, like Collection.shuffle() does:

The access via reflection needs a bit time, so this solution is faster only for higher number of elements.

I would not reccomend this solution unless you want to win the race, having the fastes shuffle, also by means of execution time.

And as always when comparing speeds, make sure you warm up the VM by running the algorithm to be measured 1000 times before starting the measuring.

Comment: I tried the Fisher-Yates shuffle vs. Collections.shuffle() on Integer[] and ArrayList<Integer> respectively and interestingly found that Collections was faster.

Comment: You could also try out the src code of Collections.shuffle applied to an int[] , and don't forget in time measures to warm up the VM before measuring, otherwise the second algorithm is likely to be faster. src of shuffle: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `Collections.shuffle()` runs in **O(N)** time.

> This method runs in linear time. If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this implementation dumps the specified list into an array before shuffling it, and dumps the shuffled array back into the list. This avoids the quadratic behavior that would result from shuffling a "sequential access" list in place.

I recommend you use the `public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd)` overload, although the performance benefit will probably be negligible.

Improving the performance will be difficult unless you allow some bias, such as with partial shuffling (only a segment of the list gets re-shuffled each time) or under-shuffling. Under-shuffling means writing your own Fisher-Yates routine and skipping certain list indices during the reverse traversal; for example, you could skip all odd indices. However the end of your list would receive less shuffling than the front which is another form of bias.

If you had a fixed list size `M`, you might consider caching some large number `N` of different fixed index permutations (`0` to `M-1` in random order) in memory at application startup. Then you could just randomly select one of these pre-orderings whenever you iterate the collection and just iterate according to that particular previously defined permutation. If `N` were large (say 1000 or more), the overall bias would be small (and also relatively uniform) and would be very fast. However you noted your list slowly grows, so this approach wouldn't be viable.